# How to make cargo use another path to compile instead of /tmp (No space left on device (os error 28))

Tags: linux, rust, debian, rust-cargo

I'm on Debian 11 with a LUKS encrypted SSD, my */tmp*, */var* and */home* folders are in separated partitions (I don't know why I did this when Installing it)

I tried installing deno using cargo and it throws me this error `No space left on device (os error 28)` which is due to my /tmp partition being full (it's only 1.7GB)

I've tried changing the `$CARGO_TARGET_DIR` variable, `$TMPDIR` variable and linking another folder with the same name as the folder cargo was using to build (`cargo-installA5Ssau` at that time) and none worked

Is there a way I can make cargo use another directory other than */tmp* or increase the size of */tmp* (this one is my second choice as I guess it'll be harder)?

Comment: As near as I can tell, this is still an open issue to have a separate location for the tempfiles cargo creates when you run `cargo install`; you may be better off asking in the unix stackexchange on increasing this partition or even cleaning it; 1.7Gb is a lot of space for /tmp on a workstation).